# bitmaps are not appearing on stage (easeljs)

Tags: jquery, image, bitmap, easeljs

So I'm using easeljs and I have a bunch of images i'm going to recycle. For some reason whenever I try to add them to the stage stage.update() no longer works. (I used an alert to test this so it could just be going really slow **like 2 hours to load slow**).

I'm not sure what's going on. It's not the stage or that the images aren't loaded. Any ideas?
**edited
`
    //variables
    var $canvas = $("canvas"); //to call the canvas
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("c");
    var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
    var n = 10; //it will be a 10x10 board
    var cw = 50;//each cell will be 50px wide
    var x, y;
    var moves = 0;
    var rows = []; //will be an array of arrays
    var pieces = []; //will be the image array of arrays

```
//preloadjs images
//queue.installPlugin(stage); //don't think i need this
queue.on("complete", handleComplete, this);
queue.loadManifest([
    {id:"imgA", src:'DNA/a.png'},
    {id:"imgC", src:'DNA/c.png'},
    {id:"imgG", src:'DNA/g.png'},
    {id:"imgT", src:'DNA/t.png'},
    {id:"imgX", src:'DNA/x.png'}
]);

function handleComplete(){
    var image = queue.getResult("imgA");

    var pic =  new createjs.Bitmap(image);
        pic.y = 5;
        pic.x = 5;
    stage.addChild(pic);
    stage.update();
}
```

**still not working and I have added preloadJS to my collection of libraries

Everything is sourced correctly, but it's still not working?
I have the stage declared and it says that it's not crashing so i'm not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is being draw?

- If yes: your images are in an invalid location; or, you are trying to use the images before the loading (in this case, your preload is incorrect).
- If not: you are using an invalid name to the canvas (take a look at the line that you are creating the stage, compare with the id of the canvas).

Some other notes:

- You can use PreloadJS to preload your assets, there is no need to implement this from scratch.
- There is no need to call "stage.clear", "stage.removeAllChildren" and "stage.update" at the beggining, the stage is already empty.
- You just need to call "stage.update" once, after all changes in the stage or the children objects. As you've done, you are forcing the stage to draw several times before a single canvas draw.

Comment: Thanks!
The text is showing. The locations should be valid(100,100) since the canvas is 600x600. So what is the best way to make sure they are loaded?I've seen people use .onload(img.src) and have it work properly.

Comment: Because you have many images, I recommend you to use the PreloadJS library, which you can find on http://createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS . I've made a tutorial which shows the use o onload with easeljs http://guineashots.com/2014/04/11/getting-started-with-easeljs/

Comment: It's still not working? I've added and updated version of my code. I only have ONE image currently trying to load and I can't get anything to show up? Tested in Chrome and FF

Comment: Are you running a web server to test this? If yes try to access the image directly via url. (e.g., http://127.0.0.1:9000/DNA/a.png). If not, that's probably the cause

Comment: I am now running it on a web server and tried to run it as DNA/a.png and it didn't work. I'm not sure how adding 127.0.0.1:9000 would help?

Comment: Put your server ip and port, that link was just an example.